# How would you decide which element to be used as pivot in quick sort?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

Choosing a random element or middle element minimizes the chance of worst case. 
But given a random input array, there is still probability that the element which we choose as random or middle can result into worst case. 
Is there any way, we can decide which pivot element to be used based on input provided ? instead of considering minimal chances of worst case

Answer (score 0):

The pivot element is chosen in mostly three ways:

1. Middle element
2. Random element
3. Last element

The above three guarantees that the random element is chosen in `O(1)` time. Need to make sure that the algorithm to chose pivot element is `O(1)` otherwise the overall time complexity of Quick sort will become `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Overall time complexity already is O(n^2) with those O(1) pivots as well. Do you mean Θ(n^2)? And why do you think pivot choice needs to be O(1)? Next step is the actual partition work, which is O(n) anyway, so O(n) for pivot choice doesn't change the overall complexity.

Comment: @HeapOverflow No it does. On every iteration if you chose an element which takes O(n) time the overall time complexity will increase.

Comment: Not if that "n" means the obvious, the size of the subarray the recursive quicksort call is sorting.

Comment: @HeapOverflow It will be `O(k)` where k is the size of the subarray.

Comment: What will be O(k)?

Comment: choosing pivot is always O(1) as its just selection one element. the issue is with partitioning. we need to choose such pivot element which spilts array equally so from there sorting will takes place on less num of elements (on sub array). if pivor splits array into one large and one small array then the time complexity will increase as it has to again perform sort on elements which is closer to n. so my question was how would you decide which pivot ?

Comment: @MadhumatiHosamani Selecting one element does not mean it will take `O(1)` time. For example if you want to find the largest element in an array, you will need to traverse the whole array which is `O(n)`.